# What are the most important updated points from django since 1.5.8?

Tags: python, django

I've an application that still uses Django 1.5.8, there's a lot of work to do in an update, I need to figure what are the most important changes since that version. Like major bugfixes, new tools, new libraries, new scallable contents.
That's a lot of info, I'm aware of that. If there's a link where I can find It, I just havenát found it yet.
Thanks in advance!
Cheers!!!

Comment: Like in [django release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/#id4) and then read upwards?

Comment: Hahahaha a I said, i just havent found it yet. Readint it now. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this site](https://www.seedinvest.com/labs/backend/upgrading-from-django-1-4-to-django-1-7) that explains important topics to take care when upgrading from Django 1.4 to 1.7:

Summarizing:

1. Adding a **SECRET_KEY** to your settings.py
   Changed in Django 1.5, Django now requires every project to have a SECRET_KEY. It will refuse to start without a key.
2. The concept of  Applications and applications registry in 1.7.
3. Upgrading Django template **url tags** to use new syntax introduced in Django 1.5:
4. **App Labels.** As a rule of thumb, I would just add app_label to all the models Meta class and set it to the package (folder) name.
5. **Migrations.** With Django 1.7 you no longer need south, since migrations are now built-in.
6. **Urls.py**. You might have the following in all your urls.py:

   ```
   from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
   ```

   You will want to replace that with:

   ```
   from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
   ```
7. **HttpResponse.** If there is any code that sets the mimetype of the HttpResponse manually you will need to change it to content_type.
8. Also the get_query_set method has been deprecated in preference for **get_queryset**
9. **Cache.** If you were using ORM caching like johnny-cache, you will need to either kill that, roll your own or upgrade to something like django-cachalot.
10. Remember to upgrade all your **requirements** and **plugins**.
11. It would be a good idea to upgrade to **Celery** >= 3.1.16 as well, which has some setting changes as well.

Also as other user said, you should also check [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/#id5).
Hope it works